# Is there any way to only update added files?

Tags: svn

I am looking for a way to do an svn update but only get files that has been added since last time (that is, they are completely new to the repository). I'm not sure if this is even possible, any ideas?

EDIT: well, the problem is that this is a very large repository - it takes ages to do a normal update and for most users it is ok to not have the latest version of every file but all files need to be present for it not to break. That's why it would be nice to be able to only get the added files.

EDIT: I also forgot to mention that the directories where I would do this does not contain code so I don't have to worry about breaking it. Sorry about that and thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

If you use the --show-updates flag on svn status you should be able to tell what was added, you can then do some shell script magic to filter and update the files.

However as others have said it dosn't make much sense and you are likely to end up with broken code

Comment: I see your point, but the directories I'm thinking about does not contain code. I will try to use your suggestion - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unless you know the exact names / paths to those files and update them one-by-one I don't think that is possible.

Please edit your question to explain what you want to use this for, someone might have an idea how to solve it in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

Unless they are all part of one changeset, it will be a bit cumbersome to find which ones are that new.  Anyway, like with any VCS with changesets (not file-oriented as is CVS), it does not make much sense.

Comment: +1 for the not much sense: since any change in the other classes referring to the new ones isn't updated along.

Answer (score 0):

About the only thing I can recommend is that you break your solution down into folders.  You can then checkout just the folder you're working on at the time and work in there.  Updates and commits should be quick as you're only working in a single folder.

Depending on your source layout though, this may not work very well..